# Angular2, How To Get ViewContainerRef from ApplicationRef

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a popup manager in Angular2.

My approach for this is to create a popup manager and the popup manager do;

1. Append a general popup overlay html into application component html.
2. When popup open is required, insert a dynamic component(any component) into the popup overlay

The problem that I have is `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated in favor of `ViewContainerRef::createComponent` according https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6071

My question is based on the following code,

```
export class Ng2PopupManager {

  appElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    app:ApplicationRef,
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.appElementRef = injector.get(applicationRef.componentTypes[0]).elementRef;
  }
  ...
```

}

How do I get `ViewContainerRef` from ElementRef?
Or, Is there a way to get ViewContainerRef from `applicationRef`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this possible, but it is hardly a good practice any way. What's the case? It looks more like a jQuery-ism and XY problem.

Comment: Assuming that you need to call "popup.open()" from your component or service, and the popup component is not added into the application yet. How would you design this?

Comment: It depends on design, but I'm quite sure that *to get ViewContainerRef from applicationRef* isn't what you need in this case. I would suggest to provide the question with details that reflect the real problem. Check [`forwardRef`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html), it may be what you need.

Comment: @estus  I found this question googling for a solution to the exact same problem.  I want to dynamically add overlays to the entire page via an angular service. I don't want it attached to any particular sub component, I want it attached to the app. If you don't know how to design the solution, how are you "quite sure" that you don't need the app's ViewContainerRef? It seems a ViewContainerRef is needed to dynamically load content now that DynamicContentLoader is deprecated,  right?